# Is there a way that reactJS hides the text when he goes into the next line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating a web app for small screens and also for large screens. So lets say I want to display a title `"Stackoverflow helps a lot"` in one line. This is not a problem for large screens but when I drag the browser window smaller, some text jumps into the next line. Is there a way to avoid the break and display "..." instead?

So for example that I get `"Stackoverfloy hel..."` on smartphone browsers?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: React doesn’t do this on its own without some kind of css. May you share that as well? Consider making it a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this css to that element

```
{
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Also add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to that.